# How to find nearest edges of network to a list of points (coords) using OSMNX

Tags: python, geopandas, edges, osmnx

I have a list of 1.4 million points in a geo data frame called df_SM, and want to find the closest edge in the OSMNX network of san diego to each one, it takes so much time. do you have any idea to do it in a shortly manner?
my points are in a geo data frame (gdf) like below

```
      Unnamed:  0  ...                     geometry
0                 0  ...  POINT (-117.10920 33.02404)
1                 1  ...  POINT (-117.15100 32.71181)
2                 2  ...  POINT (-117.15230 32.71209)
3                 3  ...  POINT (-117.13180 32.82644)
4                 4  ...  POINT (-116.95430 32.66521)
            ...  ...                          ...
```

and the network is as bellow :

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('San Diego County, California', network_type='drive')
```

I am adding all of my code here, hopefully you can help. To make my code faster I have defined two buffers, in each iteration in while loop, a point from the df_SM is selected and two buffers are defined, inner one for the points and outer one for network.
nearedge is supposed to give a set of nearest edges to the subset of a dataframe.

```
aux = gdf_df_SM.copy()
buffer_R_feet = 4*5280  # large radius
buffer_r_feet = 2*5280  # INNER radius


while len(aux) >0:

    point = aux.iloc[:1]
    
    buffer_R = create_buffer_around_points(point, buffer_R_feet)
    buffer_r = create_buffer_around_points(point, buffer_r_feet)
   
    bounds_R = buffer_R.geometry[point.index].bounds.values[0]
    bounds_r = buffer_r.geometry[point.index].bounds.values[0]
    
    #  points in Inner Radius
    aux2 = aux.loc[(aux['Longitude'].between(bounds_r[0],bounds_r[2])) &
                   (aux['Latitude'].between(bounds_r[1],bounds_r[3])) ]
    
    if aux2.empty != True:
        #  Graph inside outer Radius
        G = ox.graph_from_bbox(bounds_R[1],bounds_R[3], bounds_R[0],bounds_R[2] , network_type='drive')
        
        if len(G.edges())>0:
            
            nearedge = list ( ox.distance.nearest_edges(G, aux2['coord'].tolist(), interpolate=None, return_dist=False) ) 
            
            aux2['ID_EDGE'] =  [nearedge[i] for i in range (len(nearedge))]
          
            gdf_df_SM.loc[aux2.index, 'ID_EDGE'] = aux2['ID_EDGE']
                              
            aux = gdf_df_SM.loc[gdf_df_SM['ID_EDGE'] == 'missing'].copy()    
            
        else:
            gdf_df_SM.loc[point.index, 'ID_EDGE'] = "not_found"
            aux = gdf_df_SM.loc[gdf_df_SM['ID_EDGE'] == 'missing'].copy()
    else:
        gdf_df_SM.loc[point.index, 'ID_EDGE'] = "not_found"
        aux = gdf_df_SM.loc[gdf_df_SM['ID_EDGE'] == 'missing'].copy()
```

Comment: With OSMnx's nearest_edges function it should be very fast if you optimize your code. You'll need to provide all your code for more assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have added all my code. My main issue is with distance.nearest_edges. I would like to find the nearest edges to a set of points (coordinates) but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? What's the complete error traceback you're seeing?